# How to make and store methods and classes in irb?

Tags: ruby, ide, persistence, smalltalk, irb

I'm studying Ruby. I know that Ruby was heavily influenced by Smalltalk. Smalltalk IDEs offer image based persistence, which means one can add methods and classes from within the running image.

Is the same possible in Ruby's `irb`?

Answer (score 3):

Nah, that's smalltalk only. But you can use [maglev ruby](http://maglev.github.com/) to get the smalltalk VM back.
You can use [pry](http://pry.github.com) and its `edit` command to edit code on the disk and the shell takes care of reloading. But you can't save the session, only the code you wrote to disk.

Comment: Hmm can I use Maglev without any of Gemstone's server license?

Comment: You do not need a server license for GemStone/S to use MagLev. As far as I understand the restrictions on the GemStone server is the same as for with GLASS - http://seaside.gemstone.com/docs/GLASS-Announcement.htm

Answer (score 3):

@Tass is slightly mistaken. Using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) you can indeed edit methods you've written on the console, but only methods. For example:

```
pry(main)> def foo
pry(main)*   "bar"
pry(main)* end  
=> nil
pry(main)> edit-method foo
=> nil
## launches editor

pry(main)> class Foo
pry(main)*   def bar
pry(main)*     "qux"
pry(main)*   end  
pry(main)* end  
=> nil
pry(main)> edit-method Foo#bar
=> nil
## launches editor
```

Both cases work, whereupon you can save and modify the method in your editor. However you can't do e.g. `edit-class Foo`.

It does have at least one limitation, though:

```
pry(main)> class Foo; def bar; "baz" end end
=> nil
pry(main)> edit-method Foo#bar
Error: Pry can only patch methods created with the `def` keyword.
```

Weird.

Comment: that's the price you pay for having 'conventional' file-based development model :)

Comment: Indeed, maybe it's time to switch to Smalltalk if you miss it, Ruby's a poor substitute.